# Set OnTouchListener to an own created View

Tags: android, canvas, view, ontouchlistener

I've tried to set an OnTouchListener on my created View in Android.
I have to classes, the MainActivity, which extends Activity and my drawView, which extends View.

My mainactivity implements OnTouchListener and I have instanciated the drawView. It works fine, but `drawView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this)` has no effect. If I implement the `OnTouchListener` in my `drawView` and set the `DrawView.this.setOnTouchListener(this)`, it works fine, but it have to be in my MainActivity.

Some code from my MainActivity:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
drawView = new DrawView(this);
setContentView(R.layout.canvas);
drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

some code from my canvas.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<package.DrawView android:id="@+id/drawView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"       android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Has anybody an idea?

Best wishes
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the `DrawView` you are creating is not being inserted into the view hierarchy. Probably want you want is to find the `DrawView` inflated from the layout (instead of creating a new one) and setting your `OnTouchListener` on there.

For example, replace the last 3 lines with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.canvas);
DrawView drawView = findViewById(R.id.drawView); // Look up the inflated DrawView
drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a game i'm developing.

Don't really know why this is working with me. but i assign the touchListener to the same view. I assume you implement OnTouchlistener on DrawView class (and extend View) so:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
drawView = new DrawView(this);
drawView.setOnTouchListener(drawView);
setContentView(R.layout.canvas);
```

so, before setContentView, assign setOnTouchListener to the drawView, again, i don't know why but this actually worked with me. hope it helps.